# OpenGL 3.2 on 18.04 VirtualBox guest: Is it possible?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, c++, opengl

I'm in a Computer Science course that has assignments to be done in C/C++ using OpenGL 3.2 and GLSL 1.5.0. There was a pre-made assignment which compiled and ran fine on the CS department's Ubuntu machines, which were recommended to be used for these assignments since the libraries were all set up and OpenGL is somewhat difficult to install on Windows. So I decided to crate an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine similar to theirs to guarantee program interoperability. After tinkering for hours with my virtual machine, the pre-made assignment finally compiled and ran perfectly, but with the (paraphrased) message:

```
OpenGL 3.2 not available
Falling back to 3.0
Falling back to GLSL 1.2.0
```

Is there any way to fix this, or is 3.0 the highest OpenGL supported for 18.04 guest VMs? Maybe VMWare supports 3.2? Thanks.

Comment: ...duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858407/how-to-update-to-latest-opengl-version-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-linux-machine

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Virtualbox does not support OpenGL 3.2. VMWare Workstation does, however.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll try VMWare instead as soon as I get my laptop back. Thanks!